# How to recompose every minute in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to show a timer counting down in my composable, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

I was thinking to set a delay/timeout for a minute and trigger a recompose that way, but I am not sure if that's the right way to think about it.

```
@Composable
fun Countdown(completedAt: Date) {
    val minutesLeft = ceil((completedAt.time - Date().time) / 60_000.0).toInt()

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        // TODO: Recompose
    }, 60_000)

    Text(text = "$minutesLeft minutes until completed")
}
```

My goal is for the text to update every minute with the new time. How can I do this?

Comment: Put it in a mutable state and update the state in the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the amount of minutes as state.

Also make sure to clean up the `postDelayed` callback inside a [`DisposableEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#DisposableEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function1)) to prevent conflicting delays and memory leaks.

I have moved this logic to a `minutesLeft` composable function so it can be reused.

```
@Composable
fun minutesLeft(until: Date): Int {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(getMinutesLeft(until)) }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        val runnable = {
            value = getMinutesLeft(until)
        }

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60_000)

        onDispose {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
        }
    }

    return value
}

private fun getMinutesLeft(until: Date): Int {
    return ceil((until.time - Date().time) / 60_000.0).toInt()
}
```

#### Usage

```
@Composable
fun Countdown(completedAt: Date) {
    val minutes = minutesLeft(until = completedAt)

    Text(text = "$minutes minutes until completed")
}
```

Comment: This does not work; it calls `runnable` only once. You can use `LaunchedEffect` as in KursikS's answer, `LaunchedEffect` automatically cancels the given coroutine if the composable is destroyed.

Answer (score 7):

```
@Composable
fun minutesLeft(until: Date): Int {
    var timeout by remember { mutableStateOf(getMinutesLeft(until)) }

    Text(text = "$timeout minutes until completed")

    LaunchedEffect(timeout) {
        if (timeout > 0) {
            delay(1000 * 60)
            timeout -= 1
        }
    }
}

private fun getMinutesLeft(until: Date): Int {
    return ceil((until.time - Date().time) / 60_000.0).toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `ViewModel` with the [**`CountDownTimer`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) class.

Something like:

```
 val countTimeViewModel : CountTimeViewModel = viewModel()
 val minutes  = countTimeViewModel.minutes.observeAsState(60)

  Button( onClick={ 
       countTimeViewModel.onStartClicked(60000*60) } 
  ){
        Text("Start")
  }

  Text(""+minutes.value)
```

with:

```
class CountTimeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var timer: CountDownTimer? = null

    private val _minutes = MutableLiveData(totalTime)
    val minutes: LiveData<Int> get() =  _minutes
   
    private var totalTime : Long = 0L

    fun startCountDown() {

        timer = object : CountDownTimer(totalTime, 60000) {
            override fun onTick(millisecs: Long) {

                // Minutes
                val minutes = (millisecs / MSECS_IN_SEC / SECS_IN_MINUTES % SECS_IN_MINUTES).toInt()
                _minutes.postValue(minutes)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
               //...countdown completed

            }
        }

    }

    fun onStartClicked(totalTime : Long) {
        this.totalTime = totalTime
        startCountDown()
        timer?.start()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        timer?.cancel()
    }

    companion object {
        const val SECS_IN_MINUTES = 60
        const val MSECS_IN_SEC = 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: minor optimization :p can use `val` instead of `var minutes`

Comment: Two questions: 1) How would this work with the `completedAt` argument mentioned in the question? 2) Why would this be better than using `Handler`?

Comment: @DuncanLuk keep the `completedAt` logic in the `viemodel` layer

Comment: @DuncanLuk I've updated the answer with a `ViewModel`. The `completedAt` code should be moved in the ViewModel in the `onFinish` function.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not every milisecond important than my litle TickTack inside a composable can do the job:

```
var tickTack: Boolean by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
if (tickTack) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = 0) {
        delay(RefreshTime)
        tickTack = !tickTack
    }
} else {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = 0) {
        delay(RefreshTime)
        tickTack = !tickTack
    }
}
Log.d("TAG, tickTack", tickTack.toString())
```

Comment: How `if` branch differs from `else` branch?

Comment: Actualy it doesn't :). I've deleted my specific Tick and Tack code, so now Tack = Tick.

Comment: Understood you. :)

Answer (score 0):

these codes may give you an idea to achieve this goal:

```
val time = (timerDate.time).minus(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)
var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(time) }
  LaunchedEffect(key1 = timer) {
      if (timer > 0) {
          delay(1000L)
          timer -= 1000L
       }
     }
  val secMilSec: Long = 1000
  val minMilSec = 60 * secMilSec
  val hourMilSec = 60 * minMilSec
  val dayMilSec = 24 * hourMilSec
  val hours = (time % dayMilSec / hourMilSec).toInt()
  val minutes = (time % dayMilSec % hourMilSec / minMilSec).toInt()
  val seconds = (time % dayMilSec % hourMilSec % minMilSec / secMilSec).toInt()

Text(text = String.format(" %02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds))
```